# How to scan txt file for data and store in arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, fgets, scanf

I'm trying to read a text file containing both strings and numbers and save into their respective arrays. This is the contents text file I'm trying to read

```
Ryan, Elizabeth     62
McIntyre, Osborne   84
DuMond, Kristin     18
Larson, Lois        42
Thorpe, Trinity     15
Ruiz, Pedro         35
Ali, Mohammed       60
Vashti, Indura      20
```

I need to save the last name, first name and the age of the repescitve person in parallel arrays. (so I need to discard the comma when reading).
This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[100][41];
    char junk[100];
    int i;
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!file) {
        printf("Could not open file. Exiting application.");
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%[^\n]", line[i]); //Get text
        fscanf(file,"%[ \n\t\r]s",junk); //Remove any 'white space' characters
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (i=0; i<30; i++)
        printf("%s\n",line[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I've passed the file argument in IDE. I get a lot of special characters at the end of output.

```
Ryan, Elizabeth         62
McIntyre, Osborne       84
DuMond, Kristin         18
Larson, Lois            42
Thorpe, Trinity         15
Ruiz, Pedro             35
Ali, Mohammed           60
Vashti, Indura          20
┌

 t╠╠

$

M

v
9 Rì
xá

╚

±
t/╗₧8
¿≡`
   Tq töq t4≤`


ÿv
h((((                  Hääääääääääüüüüüüéééééé
```

Why am I reading all those special characters? And how can I discard the comma and save into three different arrays?

Comment: Alternative approach: use `fgets()` and _then_ parse the buffer.

Comment: `while ( fscanf("%s,%s%d", last, first, &num) == 3 )`.

Comment: And for parsing the buffer, look at `strtok` with `delims = ", \t\n";` (that's *comma, space, tab, newline*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how many people the file contains, 30 people are to be printed out. In your case, where that file only contains 8 people, the values hold by the remaining 22 lines(from `line[8]` to `line[29]`) are garbage values, because they are never initialised. As a result, strange characters are printed out.

Here is the refined code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char first[100][40], last[100][40];
    int age[100];
    size_t i = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!file) {
        printf("Could not open file. Exiting application.");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fscanf(file, " %[^,],%s%d", first[i], last[i], &age[i]) == 3)
    {
        i++;
    }

    size_t num = i;

    fclose(file);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%s, %s\t%d\n", first[i], last[i], age[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

In fact, you don't need to read in a whole line first. Instead, scan the expected data from the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not read those special characters. They happen to exist in your array, because it is an uninitialized array of non static duration. So when you reach the end of file, **as you do not test the result of your input functions** you leave the garbage in the buffers and later print that garbage.

What should you do?

First throw away your strange format in fscanf: the first is not very different from a `fgets`, and the second expects an end of line followed with a `s` character.

So if you want to read line by line, just use a `fgets` an count the number of lines actually read:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        int l;
        if (NULL == fgets(line[i], sizeof(line[i]), stdin)) break;
        l = strlen(line[i]) - 1;
        while ((l>0) && (strchr(" \t\r\n", line[i][l]) != NULL) {
            line[i][l--] = '\0'; //Remove any trailing 'white space' characters
    }
nblines = i - 1;   // number or lines actually read
```

But as you know the format of lines and as it is simple you could directly scan:

```
char name[100][41], firstname[100][41];
int age(100);
int i, numlig;

for(numlig=0; numlig<100; numlig++) {
    if (3 != scanf("%[^,],%s%d", name[i], lastname[i], age + i)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to be strict on what happen on each line:

```
char name[100][41], firstname[100][41], line[41];
int age(100);
int i, numlig;

for(numlig=0; numlig<100; numlig++) {
    if (NULL == fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) { break; }
    if (3 != sscanf(line, "%[^,],%s%d", name[i], lastname[i], age + i)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can accomplish reading and separating the data into `first`, `last`, and `age`. What makes most sense is to use a simple `struct` containing each of the names and age, and then create an array of struct to hold your data.

There are few places where you will want to use `fscanf`. The `scanf` family of functions are very inflexible when handing anything except the *exact same format* for each line. Generally you will want to use *line-oriented* input (`fgets` and then parse your data with either `strtok` or `sscanf`). However, this case qualifies.

Here is a short example of using a struct to hold the data and `fscanf` for the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXP 20

typedef struct {
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    int age;
} person;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t i, idx = 0;              /* initialize all variables */
    person p[MAXP] = {{"", "", 0}};
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (idx < MAXP &&    /* read each line, separate first, last, age */
        fscanf (fp, "%[^,],%s%d%*c", p[idx].last, p[idx].first, &p[idx].age) == 3)
        idx++;

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file  */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)       /* output data */
        printf (" p[%2zu] '%s %s' is %d years old.\n",
                i, p[i].first, p[i].last, p[i].age);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/names.txt
Ryan, Elizabeth     62
McIntyre, Osborne   84
DuMond, Kristin     18
Larson, Lois        42
Thorpe, Trinity     15
Ruiz, Pedro         35
Ali, Mohammed       60
Vashti, Indura      20
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/person <dat/names.txt
 p[ 0] 'Elizabeth Ryan' is 62 years old.
 p[ 1] 'Osborne McIntyre' is 84 years old.
 p[ 2] 'Kristin DuMond' is 18 years old.
 p[ 3] 'Lois Larson' is 42 years old.
 p[ 4] 'Trinity Thorpe' is 15 years old.
 p[ 5] 'Pedro Ruiz' is 35 years old.
 p[ 6] 'Mohammed Ali' is 60 years old.
 p[ 7] 'Indura Vashti' is 20 years old.
```

**Example Using fgets/sscanf**

You can essentially do the same thing with `fgets` and `sscanf`. Here is a short example using that combination:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXP = 20, MAXC = 128 };

typedef struct {
    char first[20];
    char last[20];
    int age;
} person;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t i, idx = 0;              /* initialize all variables */
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    person p[MAXP] = {{"", "", 0}};
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (idx < MAXP && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) && 
           sscanf (buf, "%[^,],%s%d", 
                   p[idx].last, p[idx].first, &p[idx].age) == 3)
        idx++;

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file  */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)       /* output data */
        printf (" p[%2zu] '%s %s' is %d years old.\n",
                i, p[i].first, p[i].last, p[i].age);

    return 0;
}
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.